# One best exercise to keep body fit!

Tags: exercise

I don't want to build my body, I just want to be active and keep fit. What would a exercise that will help me to relax my muscles and keep me active.

I just want to know which exercise among walking,Jogging,Running, Cycling will help me most!

Comment: Well doing some weights will help you achieve what you want. Don't need to do heavy weights just the right amount so you still have the muscle to help burn any unwanted fat.

Comment: Any of them. Pick one you enjoy. Swimming, cycling, running, whatever. All you need to do is elevate your heart rate and provide some sort of resistance (Such as gravity or weights).

Comment: There really is no "best" exercise. It really depends on your needs. This question is pretty broad and general which doesn't fit the site too well. I suggest doing some research on your own, browse the site, and get an idea of what you want to do. If you have a more specific question about something, please feel free to ask it.

Answer (score 2):

VARIETY IS THE SPICE OF LIFE. Try out any activity that sounds fun. If you enjoy it, keep doing it. I personally like to incorporate running, swimming, biking, basketball and weights into my weekly routine because they are all enjoyable to me.

I have gone away from saying "I need to go for a run/swim/gym", and instead just go do whatever seems like fun at that time. You can even buy a jump rope for a quick workout.

If you do want to get a little toned, add in some burpees randomly (every .5 miles during a run, in-between jumping rope). This will provide a huge benefit in terms of staying fit.